# Permit only 1 character in EditText and always overwrite when user input it

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I need to make an `EditText` which would accept only one character and only character (letter/alpha). And if user enters other char, it should replace existing one (like overwrite method of text input with 1 allowed symbol).

1. I know how to set the max length of text in properties. But if I set it
   to 1, then no other char could be inserted before user deletes an
   existing one. But I want to replace existing char with that new entered
   one automatically without manual deleting. How to do that?
2. I know how to set property to allow only digits in an `EditText`, but I
   can't figure out how to allow only chars. So the second question is how to allow only characters in `EditText`?

Currently I'm using an `EditText` with max text size=2 with the following code:

```
final EditText editLetter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editHouseLetter); 
editLetter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s!=null && s.length()>1){
            editLetter.setText(s.subSequence(1, s.length()));
            editLetter.setSelection(1);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {

    }
});
```

The point is, when a user enters a second char, the first one should be deleted. Making text size to 2 allows user to enter another char after one has been already entered.

I don't really understand how it works but it does :). And additionally I had to point cursor in `EditText` to the last position because it always goes to beginning which makes unable to enter anything at all. Didn't get why is that either.

Main point of this solution is that it has a 2-chars sized `EditText`, but I want it 1-char sized. And it allows to enter anything besides the letters(chars/alpha) and I want nothing but chars.

Using the advice provided by **sgarman** and `Character.isLetter()` function, `afterTextChanged` method looks this way now:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int iLen=s.length();
    if (iLen>0 && !Character.isLetter((s.charAt(iLen-1)))){
        s.delete(iLen-1, iLen);
        return;
    } 
    if (iLen>1){
        s.delete(0, 1);
    } 
}
```

I've discovered that using `Selection.setSelection` is not required in this case. Now it has a filter allowing input of letters only. It's almost the answer that I want. The only one thing left is how to do the same with 1-symbol sized `EditText`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
s.delete(0, 1);
Selection.setSelection(s, s.length());
```

Comment: with text length=2 it does exactly the same. with length=1 it doesn't work at all. It's just an alternative way without using a link to ET (editLetter). Thanx for the tip but it's not the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Add the following line to your layout XML file `android:maxLength="1"`

Following is an example of adding it to an `editText` element:

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="text"
   android:maxLength="1" >
```

I faced the same problem and found this more straightforward solution. Please refer to this [blog](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/numeric-edittext-and-edittext-with-max.html) for more details.

*Edit*: Please note that my answer is for defining the max number of characters, however, it does not overwrite upon user input.

Comment: Please read my question more carefully - its not about limit by 1 char only. Your way just wont work.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing and I used your code in afterTextChanged(Editable s) and also set one filter on the editText like this.

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});
```

It worked as we wanted.